# Auto restart pod after out of space for ephemeral-storage

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

In case of lack of disk space the pod will get to status containerStatusUnknow,
When describe the pod it seems that it

```
Status: Failed
Reason: Evicted
message: The node was low on resource: ephemeral-storage.....
```

Is there a way in microk8s to check for free disk space every few minutes and restart the pod in case the node got free disk space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`...check for free disk space every few minutes`

kubelet is doing this.

`...restart the pod in case the node got free disk space?`

Use Deployment/Statefulset kind to manage your pod will have your pod automatically start on next available node. Eg. when the disk pressure is cleared, or you start a new node, or exiting pod has completed and the node is ready to accept new deployment.